# Android No contact photo is found

Tags: android, photo, contacts

I need your help for getting my contact photos.

I receive all my contacts with a birthday. Now I have to tried the photo of the person like that:

```
 ...
 while (contactCursor.moveToNext()) {
  Contact c = Contact.createContact(contactCursor);
  c.setPhoto(getContactPhoto(contentResolver, c.getId()));
  contacts.add(c);
 }
 ..

private static InputStream getContactPhoto(ContentResolver contentResolver, long contactId) {
        Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
        Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(photoUri, new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
                if (data != null) {
                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My problem is now that I'm not able to receive any photo of the contacts (cursos size = 0). On the phone (Xperia Z1 Compact) are definitely contact photos.

My aim is then to set the photo like that:

```
    if(contact.getPhoto() != null) {
        Bitmap cPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(contact.getPhoto());
        holder.photo.setImageBitmap(cPhoto);
    } else {
        ShapeDrawable d = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        d.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);
        d.setBounds(10, 10, 20, 20);
        holder.photo.setImageDrawable(d);
    }
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public void getContacts(ContentResolver cr) {
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String name = cursor
                .getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

        String photoUri = cursor
                .getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));

        friendsListitem = new FriendsListitem(name, photoUri, phoneNumber);
        arrayListFriends.add(friendsListitem);
    }
    cursor.close();// close cursor
 }
```

load image using Picasso

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(Uri.parse(photoUri)).noFade()
                .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I will try to understand my fault. 
For the same contact I have different photo uri's:
- getContactPhoto: photoUri is: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/9444/photo
- contact property: ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI is: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/243/photo

So I can't understand these behaviour. Is the when the photo is from different sources? Google, FB, etc.?